# Page_Load not firing after Response.Redirect in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, pageload

in a asp.net application i have a form, and after a user clicks a button i use Response.Redirect to go to another page. But in the second page the Page_Load event is not firing. I have tried to set AutoEventWireup="false. Also i have tried to clear the cache of the browser and last i tried to use this.Load event handler but the result is the same. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance and merry Christmas!

/*Added the code*/

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CreateXML();
        PostToWebApplicationB();
        Response.Redirect(url);
    }
```

/*This is PostToWebApplicationB method*/

```
private void PostToWebApplicationB()
    {
        try
        {
            request = WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "text/xml";

            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream());
            writer.WriteLine(this.GetTextFromXmlFile(filepath));
            writer.Close();
            response = request.GetResponse();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            errorLabel.Text = ex.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (request != null)
            {
                request.GetRequestStream().Close();
            }
            if (response != null)
            {
                response.GetResponseStream().Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

/*Directive of destination page*/

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Intermediate.aspx.cs"
Inherits="WebApplicationB.Intermediate" %>
```

Comment: Can you show us the code where you redirect and the [directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydy4x04a.aspx) of the target-page?

Answer (score 2):

Either set AutoEventWireup="true" and make sure you have a method on the page that matches the `Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)` signature

-OR-

Keep AutoEventWireup="false", but make sure you then bind the OnLoad event to a method manually.

C# Example:

```
override protected void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Page_Load);
}
```

Comment: In aspx file i have AutoEventWireup="true" and of course in aspx.cs the Page_Load handler. The handler still not firing. As you can see in the above code i create i web request in the page that i later redirect. Do you think this affects the Page_Load event not to fire?

Comment: Use fiddler to check your http traffic.  See if you are indeed getting a 302 response, etc.